# MVC4 Razor View Batch Methods

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a HTML helper which shows translated resources depending on some business logic. Now this helper uses a webservice to load the translated resources.

The problem is that it takes very long if we have to make a webservice call for each single translated resource. Of course we cache the result but the initial call still takes very long.

What would be great would be if we could kind of batch process the translated resources. Like we collect all the resources that are to be rendered and then after we know which resources have to be translated only make one webservice call which translates all the resources for us and renders it to the correct places in the view.

Is there some mechanism in Razor templates for this?

Comment: Why do you use webservice for it? There are several ways of doing it, like localized resources, views and even database storing localized text

Comment: This is just the given scenario. It is used like this on the whole project I am on and there is some kind of complex logic for this in the webservice. Of course it would be better not to use the webserver, but this is something I cannot change easily

Comment: That'l be the first thing i would change